# Flutter using if statement for change widget color

Tags: flutter, dart

in my application user can be register and my application can save user information with `sqlite`, each registered user can be verify his mobile number with `sms` and user can active his account on application by `userActive` item on database

now, i have some list of items witch that created by class:

```
  final List<DashboardItems> dashboardItems = [
    DashboardItems(menuItem: MenuItems.dashboard, title: Strings.drawerItemHome, icon: 'assets/icons/home.png', forActiveUser: false),
    DashboardItems(menuItem: MenuItems.healthProfile, title: Strings.drawerItemProfile, icon: 'assets/icons/cannabis.png', forActiveUser: true),
  ];
```

in application and there are some items for registered user and who active account by sms, in `DashboardItems` class this field is `forActiveUser`

for example suppose i have simple `Container`, who can i colorize white that for active users?

with below code i should be have one white container as `MenuItems.dashboard` and one gray container as `MenuItems.healthProfile`.

but i have two `white` container

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color:
          user != null && user.userActive == 1 ? Colors.white :
          user == null || (user != null && user.userActive == 0) || !item.forActiveUser ? Colors.white :
    Colors.grey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)), 
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        blurRadius: 0.5,
        color: Colors.black,
        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
      )
    ]),
```

## UPDATED:

`container` should be white when:

```
`user!=null` and `user.userActive`==1   <-- all containers should be white
```

otherwise:

```
`user` is `null` && `user!=null and user.userActive==0` <-- containers should be gray when `forActiveUser` is true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right - the condition should be like this:

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: (user != null
           && user.userActive == 1) || !item.forActiveUsers ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)), 
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        blurRadius: 0.5,
        color: Colors.black,
        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
      )
    ]),
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: Updated my answer. Any active user will have all the menus white and any menu that is not for an active user will also be white.